# Precessing two DataStream<String> simultaneously ,to find one DataStream contains values from other DataStream in flink?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Let's say I have two `DataStream<String>`, I have received the streams from Kafka and after some processing, I have got these two streams.

```
DataStream<String> A contains values {id1_id2 , id3_id4, id99_id0, id15_id3,id11_id5....}

DataStream<String> B contains values {id2, id3,id5...}
```

Is it possible to do some processing on DataStream A, so that it will output the values in another

```
DataStream<String> C ={id1, id3, id15, id11}
```

So all the values present in the B will be intersected from A. I have tried with processElement() and RichCoFlatMapFunction but it is not working.

```
public class MatchAggregator
        extends RichCoFlatMapFunction<String, String, Tuple1<String>> {

    private ValueState<String> doubleState;
    private ValueState<String> singleState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {

        doubleState = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("doubleEvents",String.class));
        singleState = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("singleEvents",String.class));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void flatMap1(String s, Collector<Tuple1<String>> collector) throws Exception {
        String single = singleState.value();
       //this is outputting null.
        System.out.println(single);
      //s is also null
        if(single.contains(s)){
            String replaceNumber = single.replace(s,"");
            String replaceEmp = replaceNumber.replace("_","");
            single.clear();
            collector.collect(Tuple1.of(replaceEmp));
        }else {
            personContactState.update(s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap2(String s, Collector<Tuple1<String>> collector) throws Exception {

        
    }
}
```

and I am using two DataStreams like:

```
DataStream<Tuple1<String>> match = A.connect(B).flatMap(new MatchAggregator());

match.print();
```

Comment: [This tutorial](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/etl.html) from the Flink docs and [this exercise](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/rides-and-fares) from the Flink training will teach you what you need to know to get this done.

Comment: I have added the Rich function as the tutorial you have provided, but I am getting Nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

The exact behavior of your `RichCoFlatMapFunction` will depend on how you have keyed the two connected streams.

`String single = singleState.value()` will retrieve whatever value has previously been stored *for the same key* as the key for the incoming `String s`. In the code you've shared, `update` is never called on `singleState`, so `singleState.value()` will always be null.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, It's working. I will post the answer, so in future, anyone can use that.